# Oracle SQL Regex dollar sign doesn't determine the end of a string

Tags: regex, oracle

I want to fetch all prices from *my_prices* that have been inserted with some error. For instance, the pattern is **150.00** - one or more digits followed by a dot followed by two digits. All prices should follow this pattern.

This is SQL regex with which I'm trying to fetch prices that don't match aforementioned pattern:

`REGEXP_LIKE(my_prices, '^[0-9]{1,6}\.[0-9]{2}')`

So, it begins with min 1 and max 6 digits, followed by a dot, followed by 2 digits.The problem is it doesn't fetch prices with one or three digits after a dot, such as **134.000** or **23.0**. And when I put dollar sign to determine the end of a string (so the string must end with 2 digits)

`REGEXP_LIKE(my_prices, '^[0-9]{1,6}\.[0-9]{2}$')`

as a result I get all prices from *my_prices*, with errors and without errors.

Why does this happen? Why this dollar sign doesn't determine that a string must end with 2 digits so as a result I can get prices that don't have 2 digits at the end, such as **121.2** or **23.001**, etc?

This is the query:

```
SELECT my_prices FROM table
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(my_prices, '^[0-9]{1,6}\.[0-9]{2}$')
AND my_column IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I don't see any issue with the $ sign --> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b92b5d13389df75df3c9d1715794330c

Comment: Thanks for the response, but neither do I see the issue. Thus I ask.

Comment: There must be some invisible characters or whitespace. Try `'^[0-9]{1,6}\.[0-9]{2}\s*$'` or `'^[0-9]{1,6}\.[0-9]{2}\W*$'`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Yes, that's the case, thanks!